# BLE mesh Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, mesh-network

I want to implement BLE mesh in Android and researched about it. And I found few libraries named **STMicroelectronics** and **Nordic**. But I am not able to find clear documentation of these. Also they have mentioned some hardware compatibility. What I want exactly is to implement BLE mesh by using one Android phone as a client and other Android phones as BLE devices (using BLE simulator app).

Can you please tell me if this is possible? If yes, which library should I use and where can I get proper step by step documentation for integration.

Comment: To implement Ble mesh, required blemesh stack in your devices.
You need to flash blemesh stack into a supported devices for example Silabs Thunderboard2 and need to use silabs Android ADK to develop your mobile application.
If it comes to Nordic, they have their own software stack compatibilities.